# Alternate proof of Cantor-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $E$ and $F$ be two sets. If $f\colon E\longrightarrow F$, $g\colon F\longrightarrow E$ are two injections, prove that there exists a bijection $h\colon E\longrightarrow F$.

My confusion lies in the way I am asked to show this:

I am told:

Consider $\mathcal L:=\left\{C\subseteq E\colon g\left(F-f(C)\right)\subseteq E-C\right\}$

1. Prove that $\mathcal L$ is nonempty and that $K\in L$, where $K:=\bigcup\limits_{C\in \mathcal L}C$.
2. Let $H:=E-g\left(F-f(K)\right)$. Prove that $K\subseteq H$.

I am new to set theory, so please keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: You ask to prove an equality involving $K$, but you don't say what $K$ is.

Comment: I defined K to be the union of subsets sets. I need to show its in L

Comment: I formatted your question and altered some of the weird notations so it is understandable to more people. Feel free to edit as you wish.

Comment: Hint for the first part: Note that $\mathcal L$ is a set whose elemements are *subsets* of $E$.  So you need to pick a subset of $E$ and try to prove that this subset $C$ satisfies the condition $g(F \setminus f(C)) \subseteq E \setminus C$.  There are two obvious subsets of $E$ that you might try first, $E$ itself and the empty set $\emptyset$.  One of those will work.

Comment: Its the null set right?