# Alternate proof of Cantor-Bernstein Theorem (Advanced)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let *E* and *F* be two sets. if $f\colon E\longrightarrow F$, $g\colon F\longrightarrow E$ are two injections, prove that there exists a bijection $h\colon E\longrightarrow F$.

I found an interesting question about an altenate proof of Cantor-Bernstein theorem (see [Alternate proof of Cantor-Bernstein Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419999/alternate-proof-of-cantor-bernstein-theorem)).

> Consider: $\mathcal L:=\left\{C\subseteq E\mid g\left(F-f(C)\right)\subseteq E-C\right\}$
>   1. Prove that $\mathcal L$ is not empty and that $K \in \mathcal L$, where $K:=\bigcup\limits_{C\in \mathcal L}C$.
>   2. Let $H:=E-g\left(F-f(K)\right)$. Prove that $K\subseteq H$.

It is not difficult to prove that the first statement is true. And the second is  particulary self-evident if the first is true.

My question is: How can we construct an alternate proof of Cantor-Bernstein theorem, using these statements?

I've been trying to prove $E = K$, but it's not going well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x) = f(x)$ if $x\in K$, and let $h(x)=g^{-1}(x)$ if $x\notin K$.  There is some work to do to show that this is well defined and is a bijection, but I think you will be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: To show that $h$ is well defined and is a bijection, I tried to prove $H\subseteq K$ and succeeded! Thank you very much, Stephen.

Comment: I knew I shouldn't spoil your fun in figuring out the details.  You just needed a slight nudge in the right direction.  I remember hearing this proof 35 years ago.  From a set theoretical point of view, it is nice, because the usual proof requires the axiom of infinity (the existence of the set of natural numbers).

Comment: I know another proof which uses the well-ordering theorem, which is equivalent to the axiom of choice. The above proof doesn't require the axiom of choice too, does it?

Comment: No, this proof doesn't use well ordering.  Well ordering seems like a very heavy hammer.

Comment: The hammer sounds powerful but cumbersome. Thank you for your help. I really liked the proof!